# Array gets converted to JSON in MySQL database (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Actually I'm curious if my question is a bug or a feature. I have a Mysql database (5.7.17) that uses utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci encoding. Now I save the following array (via Laravel/Eloquent) to the database:

```
LanguageLine::create([
    'group' => 'validation-ü',
    'key' => 'required-ü',
    'text' => [
        'en' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
        'de' => 'Das Feld :attribute muss ausgefüllt sein.'
    ]
]);
```

In the database I can see that special character 'ü' gets encoded correctly for the properties group and key, but for the property text it converts 'ü' to '\u00fc', e. g.:

```
{"en":"The :attribute field is required.","de":"Das Feld :attribute muss ausgef\u00fcllt sein."}
```

Now I am not sure if it is expected that the array data get saved as JSON. I think it is, as e. g. Laravel's trans() method returns the value with the correct encoding.

Actually, I also don't think that this is a Laravel specific topic. I just mention it as I use it at the moment.